# Cancel / reset in progress forkJoin request with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I receive responses from an old (but not resolved) `forkJoin` request when new `forkJoin` request is made.

I'm using `switchMap` with the `forkJoin` but it still doesn't work as expected.

```
call() {
 return combineLatest(
   queryParamA(),
   queryParamB()
 ).pipe(
   switchMap( ([queryA: string, queryB: string]) => {
     return this.getList();
   })
 )
}

getList() {
  return this.http.get('/list')
     .pipe(
      switchMap(response: any[] => {
        return this.getItem( response );
      })
     )
}

getItem( list: any[] ) {
  return forkJoin(
    // i'm fairly certain its to do with this bit below.
    list.map( (item: any) => 
      this.http.get('/item')
    );
  )
}
```

Expect:
When `getList` is triggered by `combineLatest` I expect existing / previous `forkJoin` requests to be cancelled before new `forkJoin`.

Actual:
When `getList` is triggered by `combineLatest` I'm still receiving responses from the previous `forkJoin`.

I should add that if i do `call().subscribe()` the `subscribe()` is never called.

Comment: I ask think it should work. Could you maybe provide a stackblitz (or something else) so that One can actually deal with the problem? Though would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can have all of the logic inside `getList`:

```js
  return this.http.get('/list').pipe(
    switchMap(response: any[] => from(response)), // emits each value from the response array individually
    mergeMap(item => this.http.get('/' + item)) // here I assume you want to use the item string you get out of the Array
  );
```